# Illegal string offset error but value is there when array is dumped

Tags: php, arrays

Can anyone help me with this please? I have a method which is trying to use values from an array. This is what I have...

```
function createFDF ( $data )
    {
        $data = $this->getFdfHeader() . $this->getFdfContent( $data ) . $this->getFdfFooter( $data );

        $filename = $data['filename'] . '.fdf';

        if ( $fp = fopen( $filename, 'w' ) )
        {
            fwrite( $fp, $data, strlen( $data ) );

            return fclose( $fp );
        }
    }
```

Running this I get an illegal string offset, however if I die and dump $data['filename'] then it outputs what I am looking for.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've just seen what I'm doing, I'm overwriting the $data variable.

I should really get some sleep.